# Get Google Chrome version in ARC app

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

[The official documentation for ARC](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc) makes the following recommendation:

> If you need to check if your app is running on Chrome OS, look for *chromium* as the `android.os.Build.BRAND` and `android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER`.

Are there any similar Java calls to get the *version* of Google Chrome on which an ARC application is running?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that won't be possible to achieve.